# VSTO Ribbon gallery that looks like the Style Selector in Word 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, vsto, ribbon

I'm coding a Ribbon COM-add-in in C# and try to create a gallery of avaiable template files on a new tab.

Is it possible to set the gallery to open like the Style Selector gallery on the home tab in word ie. showing all the filenames in the gallery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS does not allow others to use an **In-Ribbon Gallery** in Outlook 2007->2013. Maybe we will see it in Outlook 2015/2016.

Take a look at the [MSDN Code Samples to see what Ribbon XML controls are available](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/VBOutlookRibbonXml-bc478854). The closest you can come is using the [Gallery control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd548011%28v=office.12%29.aspx) which displays a customizable dropdown grid - not an in-ribbon gallery.

Comment: Apparently you can't move existing in-ribbon galleries, like the style selector, either.

Comment: This answer seems to be specific to Outlook, and the question doesn't specify Outlook anywhere. -- But I believe you can do this in VSTO for Word, PowerPoint, and Excel (they all have regular Ribbon support).