# Excel In-Ribbon Gallery (like cell styles)

Tags: vb.net, excel, ribbon

I'm creating excel ribbon using VB.NET in VS 2010. Coud you please tell me, is it possible to add In-Ribbon Gallery control (like cell styles gallery, you can see foto of the control [here](http://www.jegsworks.com/lessons/numbers-2/format/step-cellstyles.htm))?

Maybe I should use XML for it?

In your forum I found such [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385104/vsto-ribbon-gallery-that-looks-like-the-style-selector-in-word-2010) only for Outlook. Is it usefull for excel to?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not possible to add this kind of control to the Ribbon. Microsoft did not expose all the control types it uses in its software to outside developers.